# NLog AsyncWrapper for ASP.Net

Tags: asp.net, asynchronous, nlog

Should I include an `Async="true"` attribute in the page's @ Page directive if an ASP.NET application will use NLog with AsyncWrapper?

My concern is which handler `IHttpAsyncHandler` or `IHttpHandler` will be used without setting the Page attribute.

Source:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163725.aspx